# SQL Server Tables, Views and EF Entities, I am using generic columns of type string, many of which will be null. Am I wasting space?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to implement multiple entity types like product, clients etc that exist in a report. The attributes of these entities can all be string. Because there may be quite a number of these "entities", I did not want to create many many tables for each one. So instead I have created one generic "Class" table with multiple C1... C30 columns of type `varchar(max)`.

I then create a view for each entity such as `vwProduct`. I then map these views into Entity Framework, as entities (ie `Product`) where I benefit from all the EF goodness such as Data Annotations. I use a good EF designer tool which enables me too manage the EF model in one place.

However there will be many Cn columns left as null since some entities may only have say 5 attributes. Is this an issue? I assume not as SQL Server 2008 R2 is optimised for this sort of thing. Perhaps I should be using a better datatype.

Also not sure how performance will be affected since one physical table will be queried/updated for everything via the Views. However again this is the raison d'etre of an enterprise DBMS.

The combination of generic physical tables, DB Views and EF (POCO classes) seem powerful to me especially within the MVC framework.

Thoughts?

Many thanks.

Comment: It might be just me, but doing this will lose one of the major reasons for using a relational database engine - that is, the relations. Maybe you want to look into a NoSQL engine instead?

Comment: Thanks I know about NoSQL DBs and it would be a step too far. I do use relations in other parts of the DB model though extensively. Also when creating the document the data needs to be a snapshot, not changing as FKs would do. So actually a "copy" from a lookup is better. I have been using an XML document approach where I populate the XML document according to a schema and then stored the XML document in one "Content" column. But with this approach some of the EF features become more of a hassle like annotating the classes for validation etc.

Comment: Having researched this more, I believe I am worrying too much since variable type take 0 bytes and only 1 byte if nullable. Compared to the columns that contain the data these null columns will be insignificant. We may also be talking about 50K rows in the first instance so from a MS SQL perspective small fry I believe. I will be using MS SQL 2008 R2 Web. I also looked at the new sparse column feature in SQL 2008, but since there is an overhead with populated columns I am leaving that for the moment.

Comment: This is known as the [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), and it's usually considered (among database people) to be poor database design because data integrity is impossible, querying is difficult and performance is poor. There are [numerous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eav) about it on SO already, and Microsoft has a [white paper](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx) on best practices for this type of model

Comment: Thanks for the comment, appreciated. However why is querying difficult when one has a DB view mapped onto the physical table? If I was proposing a name/value row pattern then yes this would be more EAV like and a nightmare for DB applications. That is why I have maintained the C1..Cn row patten. Granted they are not FKs, but data containers. Thanks again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you do have a view mapped out of this table, why not use the view's definition as the table schema in the first place?

Comment: The issue with using views is that you're trying to get one benefit of having separate tables (it's easier to query) but you still have all the disadvantages of the EAV model (no data integrity, poor indexing and performance). I would rather manage 50 tables than 50 views, because the added benefits of the tables are so significant that they outweigh any perceived advantages of EAV. But this is getting into opinion/discussion territory and not really suitable for this site.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your very valuable insight. I am attempting to create a more generic physical database design which can be accessed via more business specific entities hence the views. You point about 50 tables rather than 50 views is a point well made. Certainly something for me to think on. So thanks all